# Visual sitemap generater

Tags: google-analytics, sitemap

I'm looking for a something to visually create a sitemap for one of my websites. Id like something in a tree structure, so I have the hierarchical view of my site.

A couple requirements I have though, the ability to map password protected pages, and (not REALLY a requirement) the ability to integrate Google Analytics data.

Answer (score 1):

An XML sitemap generated by any of the free Google XML sitemap creators can be styled to give you the tree you are looking for.

Just like you can use CSS for HTML files, you can also use XSLT to make a Google XML sitemap turn into an HTML page.  The benefit for this approach is you separate design from content.  If your sitemap data changes,  you don't need to update your style.